# Can't find any registered devices yet Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have created the Parse account and downloaded the SDK and replaced the API Key and Secret Key.
I try to run the application and the ParseStarterProject runs with no errors for Android.
But when I try to send a  push message I get the message "Can't find any registered devices yet".How do I register my device in parse.com.Please suggest.

I have only this in my main ParseStarterProjectActivity.java

```
public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
        }
}
```

public class ParseApplication extends Application {

@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

```
// Initialize Crash Reporting.
ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

// Enable Local Datastore.
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);


// Add your initialization code here
Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx");
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
// Optionally enable public read access.
// defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

}
}

Comment: Does the starter project have `ParsePush.subscribeInBackground()` somewhere in the code?

Comment: Have you followed the Parse push quick-start guide? It will get you up and running in no time. https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/existing

Comment: Nope  I tried adding the parameter Channel But there is no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your code, it should be below in your ParseApplication extends Application activity.

```
 ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Added the above code to the end of onCreate method.And the device does not get registered still.

Comment: Double check your manifest file to see whether you've set the correct permissions. Uninstall the app, restart android studio, clean and rebuild your app and then try again?

Comment: Well the device got recognised but the pushes are not being sent any idea?

Comment: Great! That's a start, are you using Wi-Fi or mobile data? Try turning your Wifi off and use Mobile Data, I ran into the same problem too.