# Can't find any registered devices yet... Android native

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am new to the use of parse , register a few days ago and I recorded app users . But i decided to delete another record again, now I get the error "Can not find any registered devices yet ... "
I've checked that everything is correct , permits, library , app keys ...
I see this question [Can't find any registered devices yet Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658391/cant-find-any-registered-devices-yet-android) but I can't solved this problem.
They know any solution? thanks

Comment: I used a new emulator device and I can register it. But I install my apk on my mobile device, but not recorded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the problem, I uninstalled the app from my phone , previously only the updated. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at Twitter Fabric crashlytics. It provides a great deal of info from your app users. I am also new to android, discovering crashlytics was a mile stone in my app development.